# Convert a MS Windows path to short filename / 8.3 filename / SFN

Tags: microsoft-windows, path

How can I programmatically convert a Windows OS path containing spaces to one without spaces that uses the *tilde* format?

BEFORE:   `c:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop`

AFTER:   `"c:/docume~1/admini~1/desktop"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows build of Emacs provides a function for this, `w32-short-file-name`.

```el
(w32-short-file-name "C:/path with space (and parens)/") ; => "c:/PATHWI~1/"`
```

```
w32-short-file-name is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(w32-short-file-name FILENAME)

Return the short file name version (8.3) of the full path of FILENAME.
If FILENAME does not exist, return nil.
All path elements in FILENAME are converted to their short names.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a MS Windows solution that shells-out to `cmd.exe` to make path conversion.

```lisp
(defun convert-path-to-short-filename (path)
"Convert path to a short filename aka 8.3 filename aka SFN"
(interactive)
  (unless (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (error "This function has only been tested on Windows XP SP-3."))
  (setq path (concat "cmd /c for %A in (\"" path "\") do @echo %~sA"))
  (setq path (car (split-string (shell-command-to-string path) "\n")))
  (setq path (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\" "/" path))
  (setq path (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\$" "" path)))
```

Sample usage -- **cmd.exe** displays a short filename in all capital letters, but it also recognizes lowercase letters:

```lisp
(convert-path-to-short-filename "c:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop")
```

The output looks like this:  `C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/Desktop`